# Cannot connect to Postgres Database from Strapi on Google App Engine

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, strapi

Need help connecting to my Google SQL Postgres Database from Google App Engine. I've followed https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/google-app-engine.html but keep running into the following error:

```
2022-09-27 16:11:32 default[20220928t020816]  [2022-09-27 16:11:32.307] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2022-09-27 16:11:32 default[20220928t020816]  [2022-09-27 16:11:32.309] error: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/project-id:us-central1:database-id/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

database.ts

```
export default ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
      host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
      port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 5432),
      database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'database-id'),
      user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'strapi'),
      password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'strapi'),
      ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
    },
  },
});
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: F1

env_variables:
  ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  API_TOKEN_SALT: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  APP_KEYS: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  DATABASE_HOST: '/cloudsql/project-id:us-central1:database-id'
  DATABASE_PORT: '5432'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'database-id'
  DATABASE_USERNAME: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  DATABASE_SSL: 'false'
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  JWT_SECRET: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  PORT: '1337'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: 'project-id:us-central1:database-id'
```

Comment: have you enabled the `Cloud SQL Admin` API in your GCP project? You will also want to double-check that your App Engine service account has the `Cloud SQL Client` IAM role granted to it.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon having `Cloud SQL Admin` API enabled did the trick. If you would like to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: post your solution as an answer so that other's could spot the workaround easier? or I can do it as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Comment: @DallasClark added comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the causes of `error: connect ECONNREFUSED` and the most common one when connecting to Cloud SQL using Unix Sockets (as is the case here) is that your GCP project does not have the `Cloud SQL Admin API` enabled.

[Enable the Cloud SQL Admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com) and that should help resolve the connectivity issue.