# Strapi on GCP App ending: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, strapi

I am trying to get strapi up and running on GCP using pg.

Here is what I did:

- Following [this tutorial](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/google-app-engine.html) step by step
- Using `npm install` instead of `yarn` is the only difference
- Enabled the Cloud SQL API (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870911/cannot-connect-to-postgres-database-from-strapi-on-google-app-engine))
- Gave the App Engine default service account the "Cloud-SQL-Agent" role
- Changed the content of database.js from environment to static strings

After a lot of experimenting and trying different things I still get the following error:

```
2023-02-21 06:24:31 default[20230221t070653]  [2023-02-21 06:24:31.418] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2023-02-21 06:24:31 default[20230221t070653]  [2023-02-21 06:24:31.421] error: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/myproject-123:europe-west1:postgres-strapi/.s.PGSQL.5432
2023-02-21 06:24:31 default[20230221t070653]  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/myproject-123:europe-west1:postgres-strapi/.s.PGSQL.5432      at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
```

This is the app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'strapi'
  DATABASE_USER: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'password'
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: 'myproject-123:europe-west1:postgres-strapi'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: 'myproject-123:europe-west1:postgres-strapi'
```

The public IP box in the SQL connections is checked and the App engine is in the same project - so according to the page it should be authenticated by default.

The APIs that are activated are:

- Compute Engine API
- Cloud SQL
- sqladmin API (prod)

and a few more that do not show any traffic.

The sqladmin API shows 100% error rate when the following method is called: `google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GenerateEphemeralCert`

I don't have any "Cloud SQL admin" specific role that I could assign to the app engine service account in the IAM panel (as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard?hl=de)).

Most likely I am overlooking something very obvious. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your `app.yaml` and the db has public ip?

Comment: @Puteri Added the app.yaml to the post and the db has a public ip. The app engine runs on the same account.

Comment: It looks like you have enabled Cloud SQL API. You need to enable Cloud SQL Admin API to overcome this issue. It is common issue mentioned in the same [Documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/google-app-engine.html#connect-econnrefused-cloudsql-strapi-0000-europe-west1-strapi-s-pgsql-5432) you are referring to in the troubleshooting section. Can you double check on this.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni - you are most likely right with the issue being in the admin API. While it is active there is no role that I could assign to the app engine account. Not completely sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECONNREFUSED error occurs when the request to establish a connection with another service is rejected. There might be different reasons for this issue. You can check with points:

As I suggested in the Comments section, It looks like you have enabled Cloud SQL API. You need to enable Cloud SQL Admin API to overcome this issue. It is a common issue mentioned in the same [Documentation-1](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment#connect-econnrefused-cloudsql-strapi-0000-europe-west1-strapi-s-pgsql-5432) you are referring to in the troubleshooting section. Can you double check on this.

Also seems like you have enabled the Cloud - SQL Agent role. Instead can you try giving the App Engine default service account the "Cloud-SQL-Client" role as suggested in the [Documentation-2](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#node.js:%7E:text=Cloud%20SQL%20Client%20(preferred)).

Also you need to check with your Network configuration. There might be a possibility that the issue is related to using VPC with Cloud SQL with egress settings. As stated in the [Documentation-3](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#node.js:%7E:text=If%20you%20route%20all%20egress%20traffic%20through%20the%20VPC%20connector%2C%20you%20must%20use%20a%20Private%20IP.)

> If you route all egress traffic through the VPC connector, you must use a Private IP.

Also check whether you are using the older versions of Node.js, Npm, Strapi. Try to update to the latest version and see.

If you still get the error, try to raise a support ticket [here](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) as it requires project-inspection to find the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to wipe the project on gcp and initiate a new one to select the "Cloud SQL Admin Role". Don't know what I messed up with the old one but there the role did not show up in IAM.

Comment: Thanks! Took me an hour of struggling and this solved it instantly!

Comment: It should really be documented more clearly in the tutorials, etc.